# Representing and handling Data Sizes

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

In a *very* specific application I have, I needed the ability to easily convert between different data sizes. I.e. when I give an input of 1,048,576KiB, I needed it to say 1GiB, etc.

So, I built a `struct` for it.

It's pretty robust, includes operations for subtraction, addition, multiplication and division, `==` and `!=`, `IsSame` etc.

I'd like to think it might be useful for others as well.

First bit is the `struct`:

```
public struct DataSize
{
    public ulong SizeInBytes { get; }
    public SizeScale Scale { get; }
    public double Size => GetSize(Scale);

    public DataSize(ulong sizeInBytes)
    {
        Scale = SizeScale.Bytes;
        SizeInBytes = sizeInBytes;
    }

    public DataSize(ulong sizeInBytes, SizeScale scale)
    {
        Scale = scale;
        SizeInBytes = sizeInBytes;
    }

    public DataSize(double size, SizeScale scale)
    {
        Scale = scale;

        if (scale == SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            SizeInBytes = (uint)(size / 8);
            return;
        }

        if (((int)scale & 0x03) == (int)SizeScale.Bytes)
        {
            SizeInBytes = (uint)(size * Math.Pow(10, 3 * (((int)scale & 0xFF00) >> 8)));
            return;
        }

        SizeInBytes = (uint)(size * Math.Pow(2, 10 * (((int)scale & 0xFF00) >> 8)));
    }

    public double GetSize(SizeScale scale)
    {
        if (scale == SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            return SizeInBytes * 8.0;
        }

        if (((int)scale & 0x03) == (int)SizeScale.Bytes)
        {
            return SizeInBytes / Math.Pow(10, 3 * (((int)scale & 0xFF00) >> 8));
        }

        return SizeInBytes / Math.Pow(2, 10 * (((int)scale & 0xFF00) >> 8));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="DataSize"/> that is the highest value which will have a non-zero whole-number <see cref="Size"/> component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scaleType">When set to <see cref="SizeScale.Bytes"/> the result will be a <code>B</code> type, when set to <see cref="SizeScale.Bits"/> the result will be a <code>iB</code> type. If set to <see cref="SizeScale.None"/> the same base unit as the source value will be used.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DataSize"/> object.</returns>
    public DataSize GetLargestWholeSize(SizeScale scaleType = SizeScale.None)
    {
        var limit = 1000ul;

        if (scaleType == SizeScale.None)
        {
            scaleType = (SizeScale)((int)Scale & 0x00FF);
        }

        if (scaleType == SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            limit = 1024ul;
        }

        var iterations = 0;
        var currSize = (double)SizeInBytes;

        while (currSize >= limit)
        {
            currSize /= limit;
            iterations++;
        }

        return new DataSize(currSize, (SizeScale)((iterations << 8) | ((int)scaleType & 0x00FF)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="DataSize"/> that is the smallest value which will have a zero whole-number <see cref="Size"/> component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scaleType">When set to <see cref="SizeScale.Bytes"/> the result will be a <code>B</code> type, when set to <see cref="SizeScale.Bits"/> the result will be a <code>iB</code> type. If set to <see cref="SizeScale.None"/> the same base unit as the source value will be used.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DataSize"/> object.</returns>
    public DataSize GetSmallestPartialSize(SizeScale scaleType = SizeScale.None)
    {
        var limit = 1000ul;

        if (scaleType == SizeScale.None)
        {
            scaleType = (SizeScale)((int)Scale & 0x00FF);
        }

        if (scaleType == SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            limit = 1024ul;
        }

        var iterations = 0;
        var currSize = (double)SizeInBytes;

        while (currSize >= limit)
        {
            currSize /= limit;
            iterations++;
        }

        iterations++;

        return new DataSize(currSize, (SizeScale)((iterations << 8) | ((int)scaleType & 0x00FF)));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is DataSize && (DataSize)obj == this;

    public override int GetHashCode() => Size.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => $"{Size} {Scale.Abbreviation()}";

    public string ToString(string numberFormat) => $"{Size.ToString(numberFormat)} {Scale.Abbreviation()}";

    public string ToString(SizeScale scale) => $"{GetSize(scale)} {scale.Abbreviation()}";

    public string ToString(string numberFormat, SizeScale scale) => $"{GetSize(scale).ToString(numberFormat)} {scale.Abbreviation()}";

    public bool IsSame(DataSize comparison) => SizeInBytes == comparison.SizeInBytes && Scale == comparison.Scale;

    public static bool IsSame(DataSize left, DataSize right) => left.SizeInBytes == right.SizeInBytes && left.Scale == right.Scale;

    public static bool operator ==(DataSize left, DataSize right) => left.SizeInBytes == right.SizeInBytes;

    public static bool operator !=(DataSize left, DataSize right) => left.SizeInBytes != right.SizeInBytes;

    public static DataSize operator +(DataSize left, DataSize right) => new DataSize(left.SizeInBytes + right.SizeInBytes, left.Scale);

    public static DataSize operator -(DataSize left, DataSize right) => new DataSize(left.SizeInBytes - right.SizeInBytes, left.Scale);

    public static DataSize operator *(DataSize left, ulong right) => new DataSize(left.SizeInBytes * right, left.Scale);

    public static DataSize operator /(DataSize left, ulong right) => new DataSize(left.SizeInBytes / right, left.Scale);

    public static DataSize operator *(DataSize left, double right) => new DataSize((ulong)(left.SizeInBytes * right), left.Scale);

    public static DataSize operator /(DataSize left, double right) => new DataSize((ulong)(left.SizeInBytes / right), left.Scale);
}
```

Next I have a `SizeScale` enum:

```
public static class SizeScaleExtensions
{
    public static string Abbreviation(this SizeScale scale)
    {
        if (scale == SizeScale.None)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (scale == SizeScale.Bytes)
        {
            return "B";
        }

        if (scale == SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            return "b";
        }

        var firstLetter = scale.ToString()[0] + "";

        if (((int)scale & 0x00FF) == (int)SizeScale.Bits)
        {
            return firstLetter + "iB";
        }

        return firstLetter + "B";
    }
}

public enum SizeScale : int
{
    None = 0x0000,
    Bytes = 0x0001,
    Bits = 0x0002,
    Kilobytes = 0x0101,
    Kibibytes = 0x0102,
    Megabytes = 0x0201,
    Mebibytes = 0x0202,
    Gigabytes = 0x0301,
    Gibibytes = 0x0302,
    Terabytes = 0x0401,
    Tibibytes = 0x0402,
    Petabytes = 0x0501,
    Pibibytes = 0x0502,
    Exabytes = 0x0601,
    Exbibytes = 0x0602,
    Zettabyts = 0x0701,
    Zebibytes = 0x0702,
    Yottabytes = 0x0801,
    Yobibytes = 0x0802,
}
```

Both the extensions and that enum declaration are in the same file, which means that the extension method is easily available.

Lastly, I have some tests (I know I need a *lot* more):

```
[TestClass]
public class DataSizeTests
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1_SizeScale_Bits()
    {
        var expected = 8.0;
        var input = 1u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Bits);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.0;
        var input = 1u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1000_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = 1000.0;
        var input = 1000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1024_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = 1024.0;
        var input = 1024u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1000_SizeScale_Kilobytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.0;
        var input = 1000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Kilobytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1024_SizeScale_Kilobytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.024;
        var input = 1024u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Kilobytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1000_SizeScale_Kibibytes()
    {
        var expected = 0.9765625;
        var input = 1000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Kibibytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1024_SizeScale_Kibibytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.0;
        var input = 1024u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Kibibytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1000000000_SizeScale_Gigabytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.0;
        var input = 1000000000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Gigabytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1073741824_SizeScale_Gigabytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.073741824;
        var input = 1073741824ul;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Gigabytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1000000000_SizeScale_Gibibytes()
    {
        var expected = 0.931322574615478515625;
        var input = 1000000000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Gibibytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetSize_1073741824_SizeScale_Gibibytes()
    {
        var expected = 1.0;
        var input = 1073741824ul;

        var actual = new DataSize(input).GetSize(SizeScale.Gibibytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void Construct_8_SizeScale_Bits()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(1u);
        var input = 8u;

        var actual = new DataSize((double)input, SizeScale.Bits);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void Construct_1_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(1u);
        var input = 1u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input, SizeScale.Bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetLargestWholeSize_SizeScale_Bits_1024_SizeScale_Kibibytes()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(1.0, SizeScale.Mebibytes);
        var input = 1024u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input, SizeScale.Kibibytes).GetLargestWholeSize(SizeScale.Bits);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Size, actual.Size);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void GetLargestWholeSize_SizeScale_Bytes_1000_SizeScale_Kilobytes()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(1.0, SizeScale.Megabytes);
        var input = 1000u;

        var actual = new DataSize(input, SizeScale.Kilobytes).GetLargestWholeSize(SizeScale.Bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Size, actual.Size);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void Subtract_2_SizeScale_Bytes_1_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(1u, SizeScale.Bytes);
        var initial = new DataSize(2u, SizeScale.Bytes);
        var subtract = new DataSize(1u, SizeScale.Bytes);

        var actual = initial - subtract;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Data Size Tests")]
    public void Add_1_SizeScale_Bytes_1_SizeScale_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = new DataSize(2u, SizeScale.Bytes);
        var initial = new DataSize(1u, SizeScale.Bytes);
        var add = new DataSize(1u, SizeScale.Bytes);

        var actual = initial + add;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Here are the tests for `SizeScale`:

```
[TestClass]
public class SizeScaleTests
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_None()
    {
        var input = SizeScale.None;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.IsNull(actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Bytes()
    {
        var expected = "B";
        var input = SizeScale.Bytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Bits()
    {
        var expected = "b";
        var input = SizeScale.Bits;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Kilobytes()
    {
        var expected = "KB";
        var input = SizeScale.Kilobytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Kibibytes()
    {
        var expected = "KiB";
        var input = SizeScale.Kibibytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Megabytes()
    {
        var expected = "MB";
        var input = SizeScale.Megabytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Mebibytes()
    {
        var expected = "MiB";
        var input = SizeScale.Mebibytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Gigabytes()
    {
        var expected = "GB";
        var input = SizeScale.Gigabytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Gibibytes()
    {
        var expected = "GiB";
        var input = SizeScale.Gibibytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Terabytes()
    {
        var expected = "TB";
        var input = SizeScale.Terabytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Size Scale Tests")]
    public void Abbreviation_Tibibytes()
    {
        var expected = "TiB";
        var input = SizeScale.Tibibytes;

        var actual = input.Abbreviation();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

All the tests pass at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define API a little bit different. Let’s go with couple types: SizeUnit and DataSize, so they can be used as:

```
using static SizeUnit;
using static Console;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double one = 1.0;

        DataSize size = one.In(Kilobyte);
        WriteLine(size); // 1 kB

        SizeUnit unit = Byte;
        DataSize size2 = size.To(unit);
        WriteLine(size2); // 1024 B

        WriteLine(one.In(Byte) + one.In(Kilobyte)); // 1025 B
        WriteLine(one.In(Bit) + one.In(Byte)); // 9 b
    }
}
```

Where library code (a little bit simplified just to demonstrate api):

```
public class SizeUnit
{
    public static readonly SizeUnit Bit = new SizeUnit("b", 0.125);
    public static readonly SizeUnit Byte = new SizeUnit("B", 1);
    public static readonly SizeUnit Kilobyte = new SizeUnit("kB", 1024);
    // etc...

    string Symbol { get; }
    double Value { get; }

    SizeUnit(string symbol, double value)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Symbol;
    internal double ToSize(double bytes) => bytes / Value;
    internal double ToBytes(double size) => size * Value;
}
```

And:

```
public struct DataSize
{
    public static DataSize operator +(DataSize left, DataSize right) => 
        new DataSize(left.Bytes + right.Bytes).To(left.Unit);

    public static DataSize operator -(DataSize left, DataSize right) =>
        new DataSize(left.Bytes - right.Bytes).To(left.Unit);

    public static DataSize operator *(DataSize left, ulong right) =>
        new DataSize(left.Bytes * right).To(left.Unit);

    // etc...

    DataSize(double bytes)
        : this(bytes, Byte)
    {
    }

    public DataSize(double bytes, SizeUnit unit)
    {
        Bytes = bytes;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Value} {Unit}";
    public double Bytes { get; }
    public double Value => Unit.ToSize(Bytes);
    public SizeUnit Unit { get; }
    public DataSize To(SizeUnit unit) =>
        new DataSize(Bytes, unit);
}
```

And:

```
public static class Conversions
{
    public static DataSize In(this double value, SizeUnit unit) => 
        new DataSize(unit.ToBytes(value), unit);
}
```

Comment: I was waiting for your answer like this one ;-D

Answer (score 3):

I've only looked at your unit tests, not your actual code, but there are a few things that stand out.

**TestCategory**

It seems odd that you're marking every single test with a category that is essentially the name of the class being tested.  You can sort tests by class name, run tests by class name, so it just feels wrong.  I tend to use categories for cross cutting tests that have a similar purpose that I might want to run / exclude from test runs.  So, things like "Integration Tests", "Database Tests", "Some large feature Tests", etc.

**Duplication / Framework choice**

There's quite a lot of duplication in your tests.  Some people like to be explicit about what they're doing, so don't like breaking down the tests into common method calls.  I don't know how tied to MS test framework you are, however other frameworks like NUnit make it quite easy to maintain explicit testing whilst reducing duplication.  For example:

```
[TestFixture, Category("Size Scale Tests")]
public class SizeScaleTests
{
    [TestCase(SizeScale.None, null)]
    [TestCase(SizeScale.Bytes, "B")]
    [TestCase(SizeScale.Bits, "b")]
    [TestCase(SizeScale.Kilobytes, "KB")]
    public void Validate_SizeScale_Abbreviation(SizeScale inputScale, string expectedAbbreviation)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAbbreviation, inputScale.Abbreviation());
    }
}
```

First, notice that the Category attribute can be used at a class level and applies to all tests within the class.  Secondly, notice that because I'm supplying the input and expected values to the test, the test itself becomes a one-liner, which is the common method call.

**Test Naming**

This may be somewhat subjective, but I don't find your test names particularly intuitive.  It's not obvious to me from the name what `Subtract_2_SizeScale_Bytes_1_SizeScale_Bytes` tests.  It turns out it's testing that when 1 is subtracted from 2, it results in 1.  So your naming convention seems to be something like:

```
<ActionToTest>_<InputValue>_SizeScale_<Scale>_<Parameter2>_SizeScale_<Scale>
```

Is the SizeScale_ actually relevant to the test (are you testing subtraction, or subtraction for specific scales?)  I think the bit that's missing for me (and is the mostly subjective bit) is that your name doesn't specify an expectation.  So instead of `Subtract_1_From_2_ShouldEqual_1` I have to read the test to figure out what the expectation is.

Answer (score 2):

**DRY**

The `DataSize(double size, SizeScale scale)` constructor and the `GetSize` are nearly identical. Create another `GetSize` that is static and requires one more argument - the size in bytes and call it by the costructor.

---

> ```
> public DataSize(ulong sizeInBytes, SizeScale scale)
> ```

Isn't the scale parameter not unnecessary? If the size is in bytes and you don't convert it to the specified scale then it's usless there. Isn't the next construtctor doing it right?

> ```
> public DataSize(double size, SizeScale scale)
> ```

Here you specify the scale and convert the size.

It's not very intuitive how to use it with two different behaviours.

How about a factory method instead?

```
 DataSize.FromBytes(123);
 DataSize.From(456, Scale.Terabytes);
```

**GetLargestWholeSize**

This should be an extension method as it actually provides additional functionality to the `DataSize` that goes beyond the normal unit conversion.

**SizeScale.None**

I don't think a value without a unit makes any sense. The parameter of the `GetLargestWholeSize` should be of nullable type rather then none.

Better then `None` would be `Undefined` but the parameter should still be nullable and undefined should cause an exception instead of a silent conversion to another type.

Comment: That constructor and the `GetSize` method are not "nearly identical," they're, in fact, exact opposites. `GetSize` takes a `ulong` and `SizeScale` and returns a `double`, the constructor does the opposite. It turns a `double` and a `SizeScale` and builds `ulong` from them.

Comment: The difference between the two constructors is intentional. Sometimes I have the size in bytes already, and I want to create a size with the specified size in bytes, and a specific `SizeScale` unit. A factory method *could* work better there, however. The second constructor does the conversion the way I want.